# Antenna Patch/Adaptor for Galaxy Nexus i9250

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, hardware

It's been a month of searching what kind of antenna adapter/patch am I going to use.

Anyone knows what kind of patch is this?
Thanks.

[image: Samsung Google Galaxy i9250]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a [MS147](http://www.hirose-connectors.com/connectors/H205SeriesGaiyou.aspx?c1=MS-147&c3=3).

Be careful, you might kill your internal Antenna connecting an external one.